# Keep getting Runtime Error '5' VBA, What is the issue?

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating code that can solve a quadratic equation, however I keep getting this error. It highlights the x= function every time. I don't know what is wrong with it, please help. Code is below.

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim a As Double
    Dim b As Double
    Dim c As Double
    Dim x1 As Long

    a = InputBox("Write a number for a")
    b = InputBox("Write a number for b")
    c = InputBox("Write a number for c")

    x1 = (-b + Sqr((b ^ 2) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a)
    MsgBox (x1)

End Sub
```

edit:
Thanks to the help I was able to run the program. However the numbers i get for x1 and x2 don't seem to make sense when trying to turn them back into the equation.

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
Dim a As Double
Dim b As Double
Dim c As Double
Dim x1 As Double
Dim x2 As Double

a = InputBox("Write a number for a")
b = InputBox("Write a number for b")
c = InputBox("Write a number for c")

'If statement to check if items inside sqr are negative. Being negative would create an imaginary number, and we only need real numbers.
If (b ^ 2) - (4 * a * c) < 0 Then
  MsgBox ("The selected numbers for a, b, and c would make an imaginary number. Please try again.")
'If the selected values for abc do not create an imaginary number, the equation is run giving the two values of the x's.
Else
  x1 = (-b + Sqr((b ^ 2) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a)
  x2 = (b + Sqr((b ^ 2) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a)
  'Msgbox showing the equation with the values for abc and the values for x1 and x2.
  MsgBox (a & "(x^2)+" & b & "x+" & c & vbNewLine & "x1=" & x1 & vbNewLine & "x2=" & x2)
End If

End Sub
```

Edit: Never mind. I had a switched negative. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you'r feeding `Sqr` a negative number? It only allows for positive. Also won't you get a type mismatch for `x1`? What are the odds you'll return a decimal number?

Comment: Sidenote: Using `Application.InputBox` you'll also be able to force enter only numeric values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include a check for imaginary numbers:

```
Sub main()
Dim a As Double
Dim b As Double
Dim c As Double
Dim x1 As Double

a = InputBox("Write a number for a")
b = InputBox("Write a number for b")
c = InputBox("Write a number for c")

If (b ^ 2) - (4 * a * c) < 0 Then
  MsgBox "The square root of ((" & b & " ^ 2) - (4 * " & a & " * " & c & ")) = (" & (b ^ 2) - (4 * a * c) & ") would make an imaginary number."
Else
  x1 = (-b + Sqr((b ^ 2) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a)
  MsgBox x1
End If

End Sub
```

Here is another alterative:

[Using ImSqrt to return a square root of a complex number in `x + yi` or `x + yj` text format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.imsqrt) - But it can be rather "complex".

Comment: Suggestion: `Sqr` of a negative number is positive e.g.: (`-2*-2=4` and therefor the same as `2*2=4`) It's just that `Sqr` can't handle negatives. So instead of an imaginary return, use `ABS`?

Comment: Thanks for the help. It works now. I just need help with the equation, as the numbers that come out don't work when trying to turn it back into the equation.

Comment: How is this? https://www.spreadsheetweb.com/solving-quadratic-equations-in-excel-formula-and-vba/

Answer (score 2):

You should be more carefull and handle all cases (no soluitions, 1 and 2 solutions)

Also, should b more carefull with variable types. See code below (comments included).

Another advice: commment your code - it's harmless and can benefit greatly :)

Yet another advice: use F8 for deubgging (then you can inspect values of variables, when running the code).

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    ' All variables should be double, especially x1 and x2!
    Dim a As Double
    Dim b As Double
    Dim c As Double
    Dim x1 As Double
    Dim x2 As Double
    ' Collect data from user
    a = InputBox("Write a number for a")
    b = InputBox("Write a number for b")
    c = InputBox("Write a number for c")
    ' First step: calculate delta
    Dim delta As Double
    delta = b * b - 4 * a * c
    ' Check, if we have any solution
    If delta < 0 Then
        MsgBox "Equation has no solutions!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If delta = 0 Then
        x1 = -b / (2 * a)
        MsgBox "Found solution: " + CStr(x1)
        Exit Sub
    End If

    x1 = (-b + Sqr(delta)) / (2 * a)
    x2 = (-b - Sqr(delta)) / (2 * a)
    MsgBox "Found solution: x1 = " + CStr(x1) + ", x2 = " + CStr(x2)

End Sub
```

Comment: @VM28 If answer helped you, you shuold accept it by checking green check mark (on the left).